# React errors indicate the compiled location of the file and not the uncompiled location of the file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, compiler-errors, key

Occasionally I have errors and the routing of the error shows into the compiled file and not the uncomplicated file. for example:

react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:117
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Container`.
See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

```
at Test
(http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4874:5)
```

instead of

```
 at Test
    (src/components/Edit.tsx).
```

Is there any way to config it so i can see the exact problem line & routing?

Answer (score 0):

try to change devtool in your webpack config:

devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',

Answer (score 0):

In my case open your browser. Then click on F12 button or click right click on mouse then choice inspect. Then click on the gear icon you will find it in top right in inspect window. go to preferences>sources then checked **Enable javaScript source maps**